# combine two sub query column id into one in full outer join SQL

Tags: teradata-sql-assistant

I have two tables like below. using full outer join i have combined two table values into one.
I want to get all id into one single column.
below the query using:

```
select sum(price),A.id,B.id
from
(select sum(price),id from table_a group by id) A
Full outer join
(select sum(price),id from table_b group by id)B
on A.id=B.id
group by A.id, B.id


table a     table b 
                
id  price   id  price
1   20      1   10
2   40      4   20
3   10      5   30
7   10      6   40
```

Now my resulting coming like below

```
id  id  price
1   1   30
2   ?   40
3   ?   10
?   4   20
?   5   30
?   6   40
7   ?   10
```

But I want result like below:

```
id  price
1   30
2   40
3   10
4   20
5   30
6   40
7   10
```

Thanks in advance
love you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following

```
SELECT
  ab.id as id, 
  SUM(price) as price
FROM
(
 SELECT id, price FROM table_a
 UNION ALL
 SELECT id, price FROM table_b
) ab
GROUP BY ab.id
ORDER BY ab.id
;
```

Using FULL OUTER JOIN

```
  SELECT
    COALESCE(a.id, b.id) as id, 
    (COALESCE(a.price, 0) +  COALESCE(b.price, 0)) as price 
  FROM
    test_a a
    FULL OUTER JOIN test_b b ON (a.id = b.id)
```

Comment: Thank you for Answer. I cant use union all. I want to get data in full join.

Comment: Div, with full outer join added in answer